# React Native Video Player not Displaying Video in Live Streaming URL

Tags: react-native, video

I am using the `react-native-video` component to play a live streaming URL.

The audio is working, but the video is not displaying.

```js
<Video
 ref={videoRef}
 source={{ uri: 'https://www.cbsnews.com/common/video/cbsn_header_prod.m3u8'}}
 style={styles.video}
 controls={true}
 resizeMode="cover"
 autoplay={true}
 paused={!isPlaying} // Use the paused prop to control play/pause state
 onEnd={() => setIsPlaying(false)}
/>
```

Comment: What browser and what OS are you testing on? Tested your link in Chrome/Windows using this site: https://castr.com/hlsplayer/ and it worked correctly (got picture, got sound).

Comment: When testing the link, it got downloaded directly. Make sure `react-native-video` supports `m3u8` files.